# Best way to request tiles from client?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to implement method of storing markers in database where markers has lat/lon and

also id of tile that contain this marker. You can see what i'm talking about here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

My question is what is the best way to make requests to the server depending on what tiles are

currently in viewport of user?

I'm not really good in js & google maps. But maybe someone already tried to solve this

problem. All i need is a sample of js script that will determine tiles in viewport of user

and request only tiles that wasn't requested yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://kashey.ru/maps/ajax-loading-as-tiles/

In my opinion the most easy and interesting way to request tiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request to your server by adding the googlemaps provided api listener for `boundschanged' and in the callback function of the same make an ajax request, google provides you an api to get the current bounding box of the map, send these parameters over to your server..

now use this to filter your database using a where clause.

your where clause should be:

```
lat>=minLat && lng>=minLng && lat<=maxLat && lng<=maxLng
```

and select whatever corresponding data you want that needs to be sent to the client along with your lat/lng and id. Serialize this into json and then send the data over to the client now loop over your resultset use google maps api again to create markers and add it to the map and you are all set.
Hope that gave a good idea on how to get it done.

Comment: Thx man. But have you tried this method - it seems to be the most elegant;)